# FPATH in zsh: functions and site-functions

Tags: zsh

I noticed I have the following line near the beginning of my `.zshrc` file:

```
export FPATH=/usr/share/zsh/site-functions:/usr/share/zsh/4.2.6/functions:$FPATH
```

I can't remember if I typed this myself or if this line was automatically generated by  `zsh-newuser-install`.

Is it assumed that the user types those paths in `FPATH` in a startup file? What's the difference between `functions` and `site-functions`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `4.2.6/functions` directory contains functions shipped with zsh 4.2.6. The `site-functions` directory contains functions that are added by third-party packages or by the local administrator; under Linux the local administrator would usually use a `site-functions` directory under `/usr/local`.

Normally these directories would be in the default `fpath` setting built into the `zsh` executable, it's strange that you would need to add them. I don't see any code in `zsh-newuser-install` that would add these lines; it looks like something your site administrator or you wrote.

Note that the `FPATH` string variable is tied to the `fpath` array variable, so you could write

```
fpath=(/some/extra/directory $fpath)
```