# Zsh completion of brew formulas

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, homebrew

In OS X, is there any way to have Zsh (I'm using [Oh-my-zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/)) tab-complete formulas?

E.g.

```
$ brew install em<TAB>
```

could expand to:

```
$ brew install emacs
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Homebrew provides it's own completion. You just need to link the file `$(brew --prefix)/Library/Contributions/brew_zsh_completion.zsh` to `_brew` somewhere in your `$fpath`.(See comment at the start of https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Contributions/brew_zsh_completion.zsh)

`zsh-completions` recently removed its `_brew` completion in favour of that file, see https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions/issues/305.

---

Update 2016-04-19: At some point([1](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/commit/edf000e4cd30c3626ccc28c52ed32f2d84a200dd)) Homebrew updated its handling of zsh completion again. Now if you install *zsh* via Homebrew it should "just work". The file is installed to `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew`.

Comment: For anyone interested in `$fpath` and `$FPATH` to accommodate these new completion functions in  `Zsh`, [this Q&A](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26555/fpath-in-zsh-functions-and-site-functions) may be informative.

Comment: As of my writing, brew didn't install the _brew file under the mentioned directory. However I do see it here: 
`/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/zsh/site-functions`
And since I am using ohmyzsh that path doesn't seem to be included  in `$FPATH`.

Comment: Also it seems `brew completions link` will add brew's shell completions to the shell. Not sure what it does in detail, though.

Answer (score 13):

Try installing the `zsh-completions` formula.

```
$ brew info zsh-completions
zsh-completions: stable 0.10.0, HEAD
https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-completions
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/zsh-completions.rb
==> Caveats
To activate these completions, add the following to your .zshrc:

  fpath=(/usr/local/share/zsh-completions $fpath)

You may also need to force rebuild `zcompdump`:

  rm -f ~/.zcompdump; compinit

Additionally, if you receive "zsh compinit: insecure directories" warnings when attempting
to load these completions, you may need to run this:

  chmod go-w /usr/local/share
```

[It also looks like zsh may have some compatibility with bash completions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249432/i-have-a-bash-tab-completion-script-is-there-a-simple-way-to-use-it-from-zsh). You could try that in conjunction with the `bash-completions` formula.

Comment: `compinit -i` should solve the  the "insecure directories" warnings rather than chmod.

Comment: for the "insecure directories" error, use `compaudit` to determine which directories should have their permissions changed